# Simple Java Graphics

Tags: java

I need to create some simple graphics using java. Basically what I need to do is draw a car using the Graphics class and make it move across a frame. I think that the way I should do this is:

Paint the graphics on a JPanel

Put the jpanel on the jframe

Then move the jpanel across the jframe

To give this illusion of movement I'm thinking that I should dynamically change the layoutmanager. Does this seem like a good or bad design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When overriding `paintComponent(Graphics)`, it is often best done in a `JComponent` rather than a `JPanel`.

As for moving the car, I would tend to draw it to a `BufferedImage` then draw the  `BufferedImage` at different positions to simulate movement.  The repaints can be controlled by a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the animation has to be controlled by a timer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a much better idea to make an object with a paint method that is a car.  Then you can move this car around the jFrame and just call paint on it :D